# nginx - how to combine redirects?

Tags: nginx

In my nginx.conf file, I have something like this:

```
...
location ^~ /path1/ {
    root  /usr/local/html;
    index path1.html;
}

location ^~ /path2/ {
    root  /usr/local/html;
    index path2.html;
}
...
```

Is it possible to combine the two "redirects" into one by using wildcards, rewrites or something else?

If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main)? What you are after is the [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)

An example from said wiki that is pretty damn close to what you are after:

```
location /download/ {
  rewrite  ^(/download/.*)/media/(.*)\..*$  $1/mp3/$2.mp3  break;
  rewrite  ^(/download/.*)/audio/(.*)\..*$  $1/mp3/$2.ra   break;
  return   403;
}
```